# Is there any chance in Python3 to create a matrix of arrays of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matrix

Let's start by saying that I am a very beginner in Python so maybe my question is more stupid than I think.

What I would like to do is the following

1. Create a matrix
2. At position `[i,j]` of this matrix, I would like to put an array
3. At position `k` of the `i,j` array I want to have another array

I have tried with `numpy.ndarray()` but it doesn't seem to work. A way round could be to create some proper dictionaries, but would be great to have the multi-dimensional array as I would have done in Java with

`ArrayList<ArrayList(Integer)>[][]`

Thank you!

Comment: "proper dictionaries"? I don't see how that would help. You haven't shown your attempts so it's not so easy to comment on what went wrong

Comment: Do these sub-arrays vary in size?

Comment: It seems you are looking for Python `list` objects, i.e. `["this", "is", "a", "list"]` and `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`, not `numpy.ndarray` objects which implement *true* multidimensional arrays (unlike what you've show with Java, which are simply just lists of lists).

Comment: What did you try with `np.ndarray` that you weren't happy with? It's absolutely the right tool for the job.

Comment: `np.ndarray` is a low level constructor that we usually don't use.  `np.array` is usually used to make arrays from nested lists.  `np.zeros` can be used to make a n-d array filled with 0s.

Comment: @JoshKarpel, `np.ndarray` is usually only used for advance constructions, such as from pre-existing data buffers.  It's not the usual user interface.

Comment: @JoshKarpel that remains to be seen, because it depends on the OPs use-case. A Java `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` is **not** the equivalent of a `numpy.ndarray` of some integer `dtype`, it would be the equivalent of a Python list of lists of int objects, e.g. `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`. The OP really needs to elaborate. Perhaps they *do* want a `numpy.ndarray`, but its hard to say.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga many thanks! I have tried just nesting lists, as you suggested, and it works! What is still unclear to me is the following: In `Java` if I try `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>[][]` It seems to me that I have a _matrix of lists of lists_ . Where am I wrong?

Comment: @ele it is just nested lists. You can call it a "matrix" if you'd like. It can certainly represent a matrix, just like a nested list of lists in Python can, or a true multidimensional `numpy.ndarray` can. What makes more sense for you to use depends totally o your use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an object at that position that represents an array.

```
    import numpy as np

class Arr:
    def __init__(self, some_array):
        self.arr = some_array


array1 = [np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])]
array2 = [np.array([1, 44, 5, 66]), np.array([90, 91, 93, 94])]

arrays_objs1 = Arr(np.array([Arr(x) for x in array1]))
arrays_objs2 = Arr(np.array([Arr(x) for x in array2]))

new_matrix = np.matrix([arrays_objs1, arrays_objs2])




for j in range(0, 2):
        for k in range(0, 2):
            print(new_matrix[0, j].arr)
            print(new_matrix[0, j].arr[k].arr)
```

this will give you:

```
#array at position [i, j]

[<__main__.Arr object at 0x102c5bb00> <__main__.Arr object at 0x102c5bc50>]

#array at position k of [i, j]
[1 2 3 4]

[<__main__.Arr object at 0x102c5bb00> <__main__.Arr object at 0x102c5bc50>]
[5 6 7 8]
[<__main__.Arr object at 0x10947bf60> <__main__.Arr object at 0x10951b518>]
[ 1 44  5 66]
[<__main__.Arr object at 0x10947bf60> <__main__.Arr object at 0x10951b518>]
[90 91 93 94]
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `Arr` here? It's not doing anything.

Comment: it was just to show that objects could be the values of the matrix, but I added more to my original answer to make it more clear what I was getting at

Comment: But why use a `numpy.ndarray` here, necessitating an `object` dtype? That is just a suboptimal python `list` essentially.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I stuck with NumPy arrays because the OP was trying to use the module originally, and I assumed this might be needed for something related to scientific computing because NumPy is a preferred library for that. Also, this the functionality OP is describing is commonly used in MATLAB (also used for scientific computing).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga and even if this is not for scientific computing, I am a little confused why it would be suboptimal? NumPy arrays take up less space and have faster performance times over normal Python lists.

Comment: @AnnaNevison not with `object` dtype, which just means the underlying buffer is an array of PyObject pointers, which is exactly what underlies a Python `list` object. Just that a `numpy.ndarray` with `dtype=object` doesn't have all of the optimized operations a `list` does , e.g. amortized constant `.append`. If you are trying to do any sort of scientific/numerical computing with `object` dtypes, then you are doing it wrong. You *may* want to just use a structured-dtype numpy array, or maybe just a Python list of Python objects. Depends on the exact use-case

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see what you're saying. I guess it depends on OP's intended use here. If they were using NumPy matrixes/arrays in order to access the special linear algebra built in operations then they may want to stick to this method. However, if they do not need those, then nested lists would be the way to go.

Comment: @AnnaNevison well that's the issue, this method would not work with those built-in operations. They require numeric dtypes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga some, but not all. Transposing, vstack, hstack, etc. would still be functional. You need to access the inner most array to do element-wise addition or subtraction, but you'd need to do that if it were a nested list as well. Also, "If you are trying to do any sort of scientific/numerical computing with object dtypes, then you are doing it wrong" ... I get the sense you would not be a fan of MATLAB.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but I am in definite agreement with you that if you don't need to use any of those built-ins, just go with the nested lists.